# How to replace a line in a text file with the latest value in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign a value to each image in a folder where the value can be anything from 1 to 6. The image is shown in a GUI and from there value (radio buttons 1 to 6) is chosen and written to a text file.

So, if I have image1, image2, and image3 in a folder and if I'm assigning values 4, 5, and 6 respectively to image1, image2, and image3 then my output file has the following:

```
image1 4
image2 5
image3 6
```

this is working perfectly with my code given. But I also added two buttons (next and previous) to the GUI so that the user can change their decisions by clicking those buttons.

I want to record the last value the user select for each image before exiting the GUI. That is, if a user select values 4, 5, and 6 respectively to image1, image2, and image3 and then later reassigns image1 with value 2, the expected output is:

```
image1 2
image2 5
image3 6
```

with my code, it is recording all values without checking if or if not it already exists. i.e the output that I'm getting is:

```
image1 4
image2 5
image3 6
image1 2
```

My code is given below:

```
def storeoutput(self):
        x= str(self.path)+ " " + str(str(int(self.v.get())) + "\n"
        output = open("output.txt", 'a')
        output.write(x)
        output.close()
```

Comment: To update a file properly you will need to rewrite all of its contents with the updated value(s) each time.

Comment: @ martineau could you explain to me how to do that in the code? I'm new to python...

Comment: I would be happy to if you put enough code in your question to make it a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? You get one additional line in the output, which is exactly what "append" does.

Comment: @Thomas: Writing an additional line to the output isn't going to update any earlier lines…

Comment: @martineau: Yes. I mean, the word is "append", which is a synonym of "**add** something to ...". How would anyone think it would randomly change things?

Comment: @Sara: You can save the values in a dictionary that uses the images as keys and the current value assigned to each one as the current associated value, say `img_dict`. It can be created by reading the contents of any existing file into it (if there's no file, initialize it to an empty dict - i.e. `img_dict = {}`). Update it via the GUI, and then completely rewrite the file based on it's contents just before exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Replace a line in a text file

**Reference**

- [Live Demo - repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TeemingViciousSystemsoftware)
- [module-csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

  > The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in CSV format.
- [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

  > An associative array, where arbitrary keys are mapped to values.
- [Tutorial - 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

  > Another useful data type built into Python is the dictionary

---

**Note**: A `dict` does not preserve the order by default, before Python 3.7!

1. File data

   ```
   CSV = """image1 4
   image2 5
   image3 6
   """
   ```
2. Read the file contents in a `dict`

   ```
   import csv, io

   # with open('file.csv') as f:
   with io.StringIO(CSV) as f:
       mydict = dict(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '))

   print(mydict)
   >>>{'image1': '4', 'image2': '5', 'image3': '6'}
   ```
3. Update the value

   ```
   mydict['image1'] = '2'
   ```
4. Write the `dict`

   ```
   # with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
   with io.StringIO() as f:
       csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ').writerows(((k, v) for k, v in mydict.items()))
   ```

   **File content**:

   ```
   print(f.getvalue())

   image1 2
   image2 5
   image3 6
   ```

Comment: `dict`s have been preserving order since Python 3.7 (in cPython since 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

The approach would better if you handle it as dictionary rather than text files. Some steps below:

1. Create an initial dictionary while the questionnaire begins. (I am assuming it is a questionnaire)

`question_dict = {}`

2. Since, you would have control over the image_name and the options (1-6). You can store each question with image and the option in the dictionary as below:
   `question_dict["image_name1"] = 4
   question_dict["image_name2"] = 5`
3. if the previous is clicked from the UI, you would get the already initialized dictionary from a file and rewrite the value of the already existing image_name
   `question_dict`
   `question_dict["image_name1"] = 2`
4. Finally, you can save the entire dictionary, per user into a json which would then be easy to parse, or iterate the dictionary and save to any other format.

Code Snippet for understanding:

```
#Create a file with an user_id_timestamp for the question session.
#Initial set of questions in the dictionary
dictionary = {}
# 1: Q1 and option selected and next is pressed, save the record into dictionary
# and save dictionary to a  file.
dictionary["image1"] = 4
# Repeat - 1, but this time with load the existing dictionary and write the new key-val and save
dictionary["image2"] = 5
# Repeat
dictionary["image3"] = 6

#Previous is clicked hence true
prev_clicked = True
if prev_clicked:
    # Assuming user is at image4 and clicks previous
    # 1. Open the saved dictionary as a file.
    # Save the new option to the already existing key to the dictionary as below
    dictionary["image3"] = 4
    # Save the dictionary again, as Repeat
```